# Swagger application using Jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, swagger

I have a war file containing a swagger application and I want to run it using jetty. I am able to use the maven jetty plugin to run the application with no problems, but when I tried to install the war file in a jetty server the application starts but the swagger api is empty.

Looking at the logs for both cases (maven jetty:run, and java -jar start.jar ...), what I can see is that for the first case, using maven, the logs says this.

> 2017-09-07 03:08:43.875:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main:
>   Scanning elapsed time=1771ms 2017-09-07
>   03:08:44.208:INFO:oejshC.restconff:main: Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath:
>   [io.swagger.configuration.WebApplication@2db7a79b]

Basically, with maven, the `AnnotationConfiguration` class, seems to be finding the webApplication class, and it works fine.

When I use "java -jar start.jar ...", I do not see that trace, therefore, I suspect, the problem is that when I am using jetty server instead maven jetty:run, the functionalities to scan for annotations are not activated??, I do not know if this make sense.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been able to fix the problem running the command below from the $JETTY_BASE folder.

`java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=annotations`

Now when I execute the command.

`java -jar ../start.jar ..`

I can see the trace.

> 2017-09-07 05:24:58.331:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=2605ms
>   2017-09-07 05:24:58.453:INFO:oejshC.restconf:main: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [io.swagger.configuration.WebApplication@3444d69d]

And the swagger api is not empty anymore and it is working.